# read from a file c code

Tags: c, file, strstr

I have the following code to read from a file:

```
fin = fopen("file1.txt", "r");

char* url;
if ( fin ) 
{
    while ( line = read_line(fin) ) 
    {
        if ( (url=strstr(line, "url="))!=NULL )
        {
            fprintf(stdout, "%s \n", url);
            url=line;
        }
        free(line);
    }
}

printf("line is:%s ",url); //this one is NULL. How to solve this? 
                           // I need A COPY OF THE DATA
fclose(fin);
```

For some reason `url` is `null` when `printf` is called - how do I solve that? I need a copy of the data.

Comment: If you need a copy of a string, a good place to start is `strcpy`

Comment: You set `url=line;` and then free `line`. Now url is an invalid pointer.

Comment: `url=line;free(line)`; <-- `url` will point to the same address as `line`, so when you call `free(line)`, you also clobber `url`.

Comment: @justAngela, will only one  line be output? Do you also want to  handle, if multiple lines contain the string url? Can you consider using the gnu getline  function?http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Line-Input.html

Comment: @justAngela, how about you read the friggin answers. COPY THE FRIGGIN STRING.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

url is just a pointer to a block of memory, it doesn't contain a string. When you call free(line) you remove the memory url is pointing at.

You need to allocate memory for url and then use strcpy to copy the string.

Also make sure that the code inside the if is actually run, otherwise url is pointing at a random spot in memory.

Something along these lines. I'm not sure about the order of arguments to strcpy, look it up before trying.

```
char* url = 0;
if ( fin ) 
{
    while ( line = read_line(fin) ) 
    {
        char* tmp_url = strstr(line, "url="));
        if (tmp_url != NULL)
        {
            if(url != 0) free(url);
            url = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(line)+1); //if you don't know why I'm adding +1 look up null terminated strings
            fprintf(stdout, "%s \n", url);
            strcpy(url, line);
        }
        free(line);
    }
}
```

Comment: could you please post the example with allocate mmeoru and use strcpy?

Comment: i am working in c. I have an error saying that new is not recognized.

Comment: yes, `new` here is off-topic, and also, there will be memory allocated at each iteration, with the `url` pointer being overwritten each time, leading to memory leaks.

Comment: @justAngela I haven't actually compiled or tried this code, but with a bit of google you should be able to get it running.

Comment: @dutt Now this is going to crash, because you're freeing a pointer that is not the start of a malloc'ed zone. strstr does not allocate anything, it just returns a pointer that will be somewhere in the middle of the `line` buffer.

Comment: Fixed, for the last time. I figure it's either close enough or I'll just remove the example.

Answer (score 0):

It would be much easier if your `read_line` function was not allocating memory.  Here's a suggested change (untested: xmalloc, and xfopen are obvious wrappers that exit on failure):

```
char *path = "file1.txt";
char* url;
size_t line_size;
line = xmalloc( line_size = 128 );
fin = xfopen( path, "r");
/* Pass &line so that read_line may realloc if necessary */
while( read_line2( fin, &line, &line_size )) {
        if( url = strstr( line, "url=" )) {
            printf( "%s \n", url);
            url=line;
        }
    }
}
printf("line is:%s ",url); 
free(line);
fclose(fin);
```